# Why there is a 0 in the start of the value of the last input?

Tags: javascript

See this code. when I type some numbers in the `.price` and `.qty` inputs, if actually the `t` variable is `100`, I get `0100` in the `.total` input. Why there is a 0 in the first and how can I solve it?

```js
$('.detail').delegate('.quantity, .price, .discount', 'keyup', function() {
  var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
  var qty = tr.find('.quantity').val();
  var price = tr.find('.price').val();
  var amt = qty * price;
  tr.find('.amount').val(amt);
  total();
});

function total() {
  var t = 0;
  $('.amount').each(function(i, e) {
    var amt = $(this).val();
    t += amt;
  });
  $('.total').html(t);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody class="detail">
    <tr class="row">
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="no" value="1">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="pid">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="productname">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="price">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="quantity">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" class="amount">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><span class="total"></span></td>

    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

SEE THE FIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/z5d421at/

Comment: at first glance, this looks like it is doing string manipulation, which is why you would get a 0 + "some other info"

Answer (score 2):

Your amount from the value is being read as a string. Use `parseInt()`.

```
$('.detail').delegate('.quantity, .price, .discount', 'keyup', function() {
    var tr = $(this).parent().parent();
    var qty = tr.find('.quantity').val();
    var price = tr.find('.price').val();
    var amt = qty * price;
    tr.find('.amount').val(amt);
    total();
});

function total() {
    var t = 0;
    $('.amount').each(function(i, e) {
        var amt = parseInt($(this).val());
        t += amt;
    });
    $('.total').html(t);
}
```

Comment: I need the elements' values as Double. So?

Comment: You're in javascript, so I'm assuming you mean you need it to be formatted like `1.00`. You can do `parseFloat(str).toFixed(2)`

Answer (score 2):

An elements value is always a string, so `$(this).val()` returns a string, and doing `"0" + "100"` returns `"0100"` as those are strings.

You have coerce the strings to numbers

```
var t = 0;
$('.amount').each(function(i, e) {
    var amt = +$(this).val();
    t += amt;
});
```

Comment: IS THIS will return Double or Integer?